# How to start android Google Maps app from AngularJS Webapp with destination marker

Tags: android, angular, google-maps

How do I start the GoogleMaps App on Androidphones from Javascript/AngularJS code and how do I pass parameters such as an destination position(lat,lon) or address?

I did not find a working code snippet yet on stackoverflow.